# What is the purpose of a resource in a WebSocket URL?

Tags: websocket

Looking at the [W3 spec on WebSockets](http://dev.w3.org/html5/websockets/), I see

```
var socket = new WebSocket('ws://game.example.com:12010/updates');
socket.onopen = function () {
  setInterval(function() {
    if (socket.bufferedAmount == 0)
      socket.send(getUpdateData());
  }, 50);
};
```

I understand that the socket services lives on port 12010 at game.example.com, but what is the purpose of the '/updates' resource in the URL? If the service lives at some port, what good will a resource do?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can expose different logical WebSockets on the same port, using different URI's.

Lets take chat as an example. You could use the URI to determine the particular channel or chat room you want to join.

```
var socket = new WebSocket('ws://chat.example.com/games');
var socket = new WebSocket('ws://chat.example.com/movies');
var socket = new WebSocket('ws://chat.example.com/websockets');
```

You can also use query strings. Imagine a stock ticker:

```
var socket = new WebSocket('ws://www.example.com/ticker?code=MSFT');
var socket = new WebSocket('ws://www.example.com/ticker?code=GOOG');
```

Comment: Ah, that's what I was thinking but wanted to make sure. Great!

Comment: We are trying to figure out web sockets here and despite all the reading still don't have a clear understanding of how they work. For example - if you execute the first 3 code, how many connections are made to the server? 1 or 3? i.e. are the sockets all sharing and connection and internally figure out who gets what data? presuming they are all talking at the same time. We have read the web sockets protocol descriptions and still don't have a clear understanding of this.

Comment: This would be 3 connections, all able to run traffic in both directions, simultaneously. Google have a proposed multiplexing extension that would theoretically allow a browser to run those 3 logical websocket connections over 1 physical connection, but this is in its early stages, and it would be up to the implementer (the browser in this example) to utilize this extension.

Comment: And adding to that: it's not only up to the client implementor, but also to the server implementor. Unless both peers agree to speak Google-Mux extension, it won't be spoken. And therefor is might be more appropriate to have i.e. stocker ticker symbols not RESTfully (read: old school) mapped to different WS URIs, but have those topic URIs embedded inside application level messages, and then run all across 1 WS connection. Imagine you have 1000 stock symbols. Even with MUX, you probably dont want to have 1000 logical WS connections.